# Mandatory variable template path predicate in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to setup a few routes in spring cloud gateway and I'm currently facing some difficult to make predicate part paths mandatory for matching.

Given the bellow setup

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: at-least-three-paths-any-third
          predicates:
            - Path=/first/second/{anyThird}/**
          uri: localhost:3000

        - id: at-least-two-paths-any-second
          predicates:
            - Path=/first/{anySecond}/**
          uri: localhost:8181
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that any path with at least 3 parts, for example, `/first/second/xyz/main.js` is handled by `localhost:3000` and any path with at least 2 parts, `/first/[xyz,abc,second]/main.js` is handled by the `localhost:8181`.

But, not sure why, a request to `/first/second/main.js` matches the first route and is being forwarded to `localhost:3000`. But the route should match that only if there is a third path on it, like, `/first/second/xyz/main.js`. How can I make that part of the path, `{anyThird}`, mandatory? Please note and I'm using variable template syntax `{}` cause I'm actually going to use that value later - this sample is a simplified version.

In summary, I don't know what that part of the path is going to be, that's why `{anyThird}`, but I do know that if the path contains at least a 3 folder structure, only then that route should match. In other words, I want to make `/{anyThird}/` mandatory in that route (there must be a 3rd path to match the predicate).

So,

`/first/second/xyz/main.js` -> contains a third parth, go to `localhost:3000`
`/first/second/xyz/abc/123/main.js` -> contains a third parth, go to `localhost:3000`
`/first/second/main.js` -> even though it also starts with `/first/second/`, it contains two paths only, so should go to `localhost:8181` (but it's matching the other route)

Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: /** matches any subpath including empty

Comment: @spencergibb I understand that, but I'm fine with empty at the end of the third path, but I can't understand why `/{anyThird}/` is being ignored... I mean, I'm expecting to match something between the slashes, but just `main.js` is accepted for that, like, `/{anyThird}/**` should not match `main.js`, or at least is not what I would expect to be... any suggestion on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm telling you that the behavior of /** will match main.js. that's how it is built. You have to have something MORE specific first

Comment: I think I understood what you mean... is there a way to match on the existence of a ending `/`? For example, if it has `/{anything}/` followed by something or nothing then match, but `/{anything}` (without the final slash) don't.